# Converting cv::String to System::String

Tags: string, opencv

I am new in C++ and I want to show matrix using MesasgeBox::Show, but I can't convert String to System::String what I need as a parameter.
Here is my code

```
projectionMatrices(Mat P1, Mat P2){
std::ostringstream stream;

for(int cols = 0; cols <= P1.cols; cols++){
    for(int rows = 0; rows <= P1.rows; rows++){
        stream << P1.at<double>(rows, cols) << '\t';
    }
    stream << '\n';}

String str = stream.str();
MessageBox::Show(str, "My Application", MessageBoxButtons::OKCancel,    MessageBoxIcon::Asterisk);}
```

and here is the error:

```
1>MessageHandle.cpp(42): error C2665: 'System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show' : none of the 21 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll: could be     'System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult  System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::String ^,System::String ^,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxIcon)'
1>          c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll: or       'System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^,System::String ^,System::String ^,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(cv::String, const char [15], System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons, System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxIcon)'
```

could someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert cv::string into System::String?   Because, as I know, it's C# format for string not standard string(std::string) in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if what you want is just a way to *converting cv::String to System::String*, then maybe this can help you:

```
cv::string cvStr = "some text";
std::string str = cvStr.operator std::string();
```

and then use str wherever you want!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to convert `cv::String` to `const char *`.

```
std::string str = String(some_cv_string); // from cv::String to std::String
const char * cstr = str.c_str(); // from std::String to const char*
```